# Laravel 4 Eloquent Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

Really sorry to bother you all, but I have a noob question concerning some code in a Laravel 4 Tutorial:

In this tutorial, we have to manage relationships between multiple tables.
Here is the models codes:

```
<?php
class Auteur extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function livres()
    {
        return $this ->hasMany('Livre');
    }
}
```

The other model:

```
<?php
class Livre extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function auteur()
    {
         return $this ->belongsTo('Auteur');
    }
}
```

And when I call :

```
Route::any('DynEloquent',function()
{
    foreach(Livre::with('auteur')->get() as $livre)
    echo '"'.$livre->titre.'" a été écrit par '.$livre->auteur->nom.'<br>';
});
```

I have an ErrorException:Trying to get property of non-object apparently on `$livre->auteur->nom`.

Any help will be much appreciated since I've already tried to find my way in the official docs and other stuff like the similar questions on eloquent relationship. (even if I'm pretty sure I'm missing an easy thing)(Forgive my English since I'm french.)

Thanks.

Table auteurs:
  -id
  -nom
  -prenom
  -naissance

Table livres:
  -id
  -titre
  -auteur_id

Comment: It seems that $livre isn't an object. Could you please try what's the result of `var_dump($livre);` inside the foreach loop?

Comment: mabe you don't have any livres with an auteur, check that!

Comment: var_dump($livre) give me the normal result for an object sadly ( i'm not posting it since it's really long)

Comment: @angoru in a way you where right actually :) sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your relation `$livre->auteur` is not returning any data, it's probably null, which is not an object and then you get the message `Trying to get property of non-object`. To be sure you can do:

```
Route::any('DynEloquent',function()
{
    foreach(Livre::with('auteur')->get() as $livre)
    {
       dd( $livre->auteur );
    }
});
```

You have to check tour relations, if they are really pointed to the correct $tables and your database table, to see if they are correctly filled with proper relational data.

Comment: Got it, edited to provide some information about this error in your case.

Comment: Ok I've found the answer thanks to your advices:

With the antonio's tracking method I've found that one of my books was relating to a non implemented ID, so I had a book with an author but no entry for this author ID in the "auteurs" table. I've fixed that in the DB and everything is running perfectly.
I feel sorry, It was obvious...

Thank again.